# parse.com java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to org.json.JSONObject

Tags: android, parse-platform

My code generally works except sometimes it crashes with the above error. It happens on this line of code...

```
JSONObject profile = (JSONObject) currentUser.get("profile");
```

It happens only sometimes when I hit the back button. Which makes it awfully hard for me to understand what is causing the problem. Why would it be a hashmap?

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

```
 ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();

 if (currentUser.has("profile")) {
            JSONObject profile = (JSONObject) currentUser.get("profile");
 }
```

Comment: post your json string

Comment: Is 'profile' a column of type 'object' in the table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem by using

JSONObject profile = currentUser.getJSONObject("profile");